# Phabricator phpunit configuration - coverage

Tags: phpunit, phabricator, arcanist

I am trying to set up a coverage report within the DIFF view for phabricator. I have the following configs:

> .arcconfig

```
{
  "project_id" : "SuperProject",
  "conduit_uri" : "https://phabricator.dev/",
  "unit.engine": "PhpunitTestEngine",
  "unit.phpunit.binary": "./vendor/bin/phpunit",
  "phpunit_config": "tests/phpunit.xml"
}
```

> tests/phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit>
    <testsuite name="unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">unit/accountancy</directory>
        ....
        <directory suffix="Test.php">unit/store</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="../build/logs/clover.xml" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

But when I run `arc unit --coverage --json`, I get something like the following:

```
{
  "0": {
    "namespace": null,
    "name": "Restriction\\CalculatorTest::testGetDiscount with data set #0",
    "link": null,
    "result": "pass",
    "duration": 0.00362205505371,
    "extra": null,
    "userData": "",
    "coverage": []   <-- why is it empty?
  },
  ...
}
```

Seems like arcanist is not picking up coverage info. I've tried even looking through the phabricator source code, but couldn't find a clue on how to enable that.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score -2):

add **whitelist** to your tests/phpunit.xml. Check https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.whitelisting-files

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: This is not the full config, we do have a whitelist. HTML coverage works properly.